# How to define a constraint greater than but not equal to zero in Scipy SLSQP

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to maximize a function in the form `x1/x2`. I don't want the x2 to go to zero so I'm defining my constraint as `x2 > 0`. But the Scipy SLSQP method does not take that into consideration and says `'Inequality constraints incompatible`. The Scipy documentation states all constraints are non-negative, how I do take values only greater than zero?

Edit: here is the function i have to minimize

```
def f(x): 
    T = x[0]
    mdot = x[1]
    Pin = 1.5 # Input power in watts
    f = -(T**2/(2*mdot*Pin))
    return f
```

my constraint for x2>0:

```
def constraint1(x): ## mdot > 0
    return x[1]
cons1 = {'type':'ineq', 'fun': constraint1}
res = minimize(f,[0.5,0.025],method = 'SLSQP',constraints = cons1,callback=callbackF)
```

the callback function is only there to get x values out at each iteration

the results:

```
Iter    X1          X2         f(X)     
   1    0.520000    0.000000    19484373451061.960938
   2    0.520000    0.000000    19484373451061.960938
Maximum thrust value is 0.5200000003096648
Ideal mass flow rate value is 6.938893903907228e-18
     fun: -19484373451061.96
     jac: array([-7.49398988e+13,  1.30757417e+21])
 message: 'Inequality constraints incompatible'
    nfev: 6
     nit: 2
    njev: 2
  status: 4
 success: False
       x: array([5.2000000e-01, 6.9388939e-18])
```

As you can see the mdot(x2) goes to zero immediately and I don't how to fix it?

Comment: Please show a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with [exact, complete error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough).

Comment: my bad, I've added the relevant parts now

Comment: There is no > or < in optimization.  Only ≥ and ≤. (for theoretical and practical reasons). Adding bounds to variables can usually help (depending on the solver: most advanced NLP solvers will never evaluate functions when variables are outside their bounds. I am not familiar enough with SLSQP to know what it does in this respect,

Comment: so I tried to add bounds for x2 like so :bounds = ((0, None), (1e-5, 10.325)) where x2 maxes at 10.325, it still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

If we replace the constraint by a bound, we can see:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(x): 
    T = x[0]
    mdot = x[1]
    Pin = 1.5 # Input power in watts
    f = -(T**2/(2*mdot*Pin))
    return f

res = minimize(f,[0.5,0.025],method = 'l-bfgs-b',bounds=[(0,10000),(0.0001,15)])
res
```

---

```
      fun: -333333333333.3333
 hess_inv: <2x2 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      jac: array([-6.66687012e+07,  3.33300003e+15])
  message: b'CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL'
     nfev: 9
      nit: 2
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([1.e+04, 1.e-04])
```

This corresponds with what one would expect (this problem can be trivially solved by hand).